# Angular: Conditional element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In AngularJS,

how would I make a HTML exist only if a scope variable is true?

I know there is the `ng-show` directive but this will not work for me as it will only make it invisible with `display: none`, but what I need is actually that the element only exists in the DOM when something evaluates.

Something like this would work for me: `<div ng-exists="myvar==myothervar"></div>`

Comment: `ng-if` does what you want, if you are using a recent version of Angular.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Angular's `ng-if` directive (see [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)):

```
<div ng-if="myvar==myothervar"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

is what you are looking all over

may be what shall give you what you are looking for. Check you angular version though.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Couldn't be easier. Thanks.